# Working with Raspberry Pi having only a laptop and a table (no extra monitor)

Tags: software-installation, monitoring, laptop

I'm a newbie at Raspberry Pi. I created a boot sd card with raspbian and I don't know what to do next because what I have is only a laptop and a tablet. I don't have an extra monitor to plug in an hdmi cable to. There is an hdmi port at my table, however, although it's hdmi its size is kind of small, smaller than on my laptop and, thus, I don't know how it could help me.

Is it possible for me to interact with my Raspberry Pi and how?

My laptop is on Linux, by the way.

Comment: any HDMI/DVI/VGA ports on your tablet/laptop are probably output only, used to connect these devices to a screen. Your best bet for interacting with your Pi is as @joan says, SSH

Comment: @kolin, how exactly?

Comment: Open a terminal window in linux and type `ssh 192.168.0.2` where 192.168.... is the ip address of the Pi

Comment: @kolin, and why would my Pi happen to have the ip address?

Comment: @OskarK. it's default/shipped-out-of-the-box config has DHCP enabled on eth0 by default, so if you'll have a router with DHCP server enabled(most of home routers do have it by default) - your RPi will obtain an address

Answer (score 3):

It's much easier if you can connect a keyboard and screen for initial set-up.

Two things to try.

1) connect the Pi to a the same router as your laptop. Boot the Pi.  It should grab an address from your router.  Use ssh from your laptop to login to that address.

2) connect your laptop to the Pi's serial link (P1-8 is TXD, P1-10 is RXD, P1-6 ground) using a 3.3V serial dongle.  Start minicom or similar on your laptop.  Boot the Pi.  You will be able to login via the serial link.

http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals

Comment: just to add some extra info for answer (1) you can probably get the IP address from your router by logging into your router, something like http://192.168.0.1

Comment: 1) there is no router, I use my cell phone as a modem. 2) I don't have such a dongle. I have only usb and hdmi cables

Comment: 1) is it possible to do that for wifi router? if so then how?

Comment: I have a network cable. I can connect the computer and the Pi. But there must dhcp server (I know I can run it on my computer). Is it sensible to buy a router also?

Answer (score 1):

I find using a [console cable](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable) very helpful in this circumstance, and much of my time interacting with an RPi is done this way.  Use the instructions in the link above and get a terminal program such as [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).  Note that the cable currently sold by Adafruit doesn't work with Windows 8.

Comment: I would have to order a console cable and it would arrive in a month only. I want something else which I can use right now.

Comment: well, I have it. But just plugging it into the computer doesn't solve the issue, does it? Because there must be a dhcp server. So should I also buy a router?

Comment: Can you tell me if you followed [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable) and where you are getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a TV?

Just plug it into the TV using either HDMI or Composite (or use a composite to scart plug).

Comment: I have a TV but it's an old one, it doesn't have hdmi.

Comment: Gerben said HDMI OR composite.  Old TVs use composite.  The Pi outputs a composite signal on the yellow jack.